# Imputation of missing values for categories in pandas based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

how fill nan values in pandas data frame ?
my data like this

```
id       state     zone

xxx       AP        south

xxx       AP      

xxx       AP     

xxx       AP     

xxx     delhi    north

xxx     delhi    

xxx     delhi    

xxx     delhi    

xxx     delhi
```

how to fill missing value in `zone` column based on `state` column which we already known that `AP` belongs to `south` only, how to fill values using pandas?

Comment: if data is sorted sate wise  you can use [pandas.DataFrame.ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html#pandas-dataframe-ffill)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
df = df.sort_values(by="state").ffill()
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

- First sort the values so that Nan should be in the last
- Then group by columns I have used `(id,state)` to fill `zone`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"id":["x","x","x","x"],
                   "state":["AP","Delhi","AP","Delhi"],
                   "zone":["sount","north",np.nan,np.nan]})

res = df.sort_values(['id','state','zone'])
res = df.groupby(['id','state'],as_index=False)['zone'].ffill()
print(res)
```

```
   id  state   zone
0  x     AP  sount
1  x  Delhi  north
2  x     AP  sount
3  x  Delhi  north
```

- 2nd anwer if you want to use only state as a group

```
df['zone'] = df.groupby(['state'],as_index=False)['zone'].transform(lambda x:x.ffill())
print(df)
```

```
  id  state   zone
0  x     AP  sount
1  x  Delhi  north
2  x     AP  sount
3  x  Delhi  north
```